# datejs overwriting Date in javascript

Tags: javascript, datejs

I am using [date js](https://github.com/datejs/Datejs) to quickly parse any string into a date and it is working perfectly. However I need to also parse a timestamp.

```
var temp_string = "1484120122526";
var date = new Date(temp_string);
```

It gives back

> NaN –

Regular javascript Date object does this, but I can't find a way for datejs to do it. And since it overwrites the Date object, I am stuck. Can datejs parse timestamps? or is there a way for me to call new Date() and reference the original date object?

Comment: Are you using the original abandoned project or the "DateJS: Evolved" fork? What code do you use and how does it fail to work?

Comment: I'm using https://github.com/datejs/Datejs

And my code is just :
    var date = new Date(temp_string);
where temp_string = 1484120122526
It gives back NaN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though dateJS does indeed overwrite the default js Date class, the fault was on my side, I did not see in the documentation the fact that timestamp has to be an int, as I was looking everywhere in the dateJS documentation not the Date one.

so the code should be:

```
var temp_int = 1484120122526;
var date = new Date(temp_int);
```

Comment: Dang it. I was about to answer this. This is why I never earn rep XD

Comment: sorry, I literally just went through documentation, saw it, tested and it worked :D I only put it here so others might see it.

Comment: That is fine. I sent you 2 upvotes since you solved it yourself :P